# CassandraDaemon keeps spawning threads for select tokens

Tags: linux, cassandra

We are using Priam for managing our Cassandra cluster (12 nodes). Out of the 12 tokens, 2 tokens will keep increasing their thread count for NFThinCassandraDaemon process. I know it has something to do with these 2 tokens as I have recycled these instances, and the newer nodes display the same behavior. As of this time these 2 nodes have around 15000 threads (and increasing), whereas the other nodes hover around 60 - 300 threads for the same process. To recap, here are the steps that I do to determine the above on the bad nodes:

jps -l --> get the pid for CassandraDaemon

cat /proc//status --> note the "Threads" value for this process, which keeps increasing

So, my question is what are the obvious reasons for CassandraDaemon to spawn threads? And why do you think those two token nodes won't free up any threads? Also, has anyone seen this behavior or any usual suspects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help someone else. The problem is with Cassandra 1.1.9, but fixed in later versions. For more information, look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5175

Basically, there were dead nodes that the gossiper would keep trying to connect, and would keep alive a thread for each attempt. To fix this in 1.1.9, you would have to call "unsafeAssassinate()" method to kill the dead nodes from cassandra ring. Use JMXTerm to call this JMX operation.